# Как передать ссылку с одного приложения в другое?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть приложение которое делится ссылкой

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_SEND
        );
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        String Body = "Download this App";
        String Sub = apkURL;
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Body);
        intent.putExtra("url", apkURL);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Sub);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using"));
```

Как во втором приложение принять эту ссылку и обработать?
Когда я этой ссылкой пытаюсь поделится во втором то на эмуляторе второе приложение не видет
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Удалось сделать так чтобы увидеть одно приложение из другого при попытке поделиться ссылкой если оно на одном устройстве. А как быть если одно приложение на телефоне а другое на часах?
У меня есть рабочий пример который открывает браузер на часах а в нем нужную ссылку.

```
private void launchBrowser() {
            new Thread(() -> {
                Looper.prepare();
                if (getConnectedNode() != null) {
                    RemoteActivityHelper remoteActivityHelper = new RemoteActivityHelper(this, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
                    remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(
                            new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                    .setData(Uri.parse("http://test.wear-store.ru/"))
                                    .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                    );
    
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your watch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "No watch is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }).start();
    
        }
```

Но когда я пытаюсь по тому же принципу сделать отправку ссылки только уже в окне на часах, у меня меню с выбором приложений выскакивает на телефоне а не на часах.

```
private void launchPlayStoreOnWear() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            Looper.prepare();
            if (getConnectedNode() != null) {
                RemoteActivityHelper remoteActivityHelper = new RemoteActivityHelper(this, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
                remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                                .setData(sendLink())
                                .addCategory(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                );



                Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your watch", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No watch is connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).start();

    }

    private Uri sendLink() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_SEND
        );
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        String Body = "Download this App";
        String Sub = apkURL;
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Body);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Sub);
        intent.putExtra("url", textURl.getText().toString());
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share using"));
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive